# SharePoint Audit Log report - content viewing report

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Hello I need to track the users who accessed to a particular or click on a particular tile on a page, as such i have activated the "Audit log" report, however, I'm not sure about the data in the "Content viewing" report, for example, Is the "document location" column showing the documents/tiles on which the users clicked to open? and what is the value in the "Event view" column? 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the Content View report, the Document Location column is the document that users view, the ‘Event View’ column is the count which user views the document. Since it’s the content view report, the event only has view. For example, in the content modification report, the event has update, copy, delete and so on.

More information check the article of [Audit log reports in SharePoint 2013](http://sureshpydi.blogspot.sg/2013/05/audit-log-reports-in-sharepoint-2013.html)